# Drag and Drop upload not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop

In my website for uploading image to server, i am using HTML5 Drag and Drop method of upload.

I am using **mfupload.js** opensource script. It is working for all browsers except IE.

Please give me idea how to make it work this in IE or Please provide good script for IE.

Note: Drag and Drop means Drag from folder and drop into webpage.

**Script:**

```
    <script src="js/mfupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() {

    var errors="";

    $('#upload').mfupload({

        type        : 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif,mp3,aac,aif,aiff,m4a,wav,mp4,ogg,webm,mov,m4v,3gp,3g2,m2v,avi', //all types
        maxsize     : 20,
        post_upload : "./upload.php",
        folder      : "./file/pic/uploaded_files",
        ini_text    : "Drop your photo,video or audio here",
        over_text   : "Drag your file(photo,video or audio) (max-size: 20MB each)",
        over_col    : 'gray',
        over_bkcol  : 'white',

        init        : function(){       
            $("#uploaded").empty();
        },

        start       : function(result){ 
            pop_uploading();
            $("#uploaded").append("<div id='FILE"+result.fileno+"' class='files'>"+result.filename+"<div id='PRO"+result.fileno+"' class='progress'></div></div>"); 
        },

        loaded      : function(result){
            $("#PRO"+result.fileno).remove();
            $("#FILE"+result.fileno).html("Uploaded: "+result.filename+" ("+result.size+")");
        },

        progress    : function(result){
            $("#PRO"+result.fileno).css("width", result.perc+"%");
        },

        error       : function(error){
            errors += error.filename+": "+error.err_des+"\n";
        },

        completed   : function(){
            if (errors != "") {
                alert(errors);
                errors = "";
            }
        }
    });     
})
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: Dragging and dropping of files is not possible in IE9 or older without Flash or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrote on the [mfupload.js documentation](http://www.jscripts.info/mfupload.php) :

> Compatible with Internet Explorer ( < v.10 ) but no Drag and Drop support, single file upload and Server-side validation.

So I guess, either your will have to edit the library, either you can use another one, like [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)